# Python - Dump used variables before crash

Tags: python, dump

Is there a way to **automatically** dump all the used variables from a running python program before it crashes at any type of error? And then to restart the program from this memory dump so I would not have to calculate everything from scratch?

Comment: You can create a custom [`sys.excepthook()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook) or just a top-level exception handler to pickle the locals and globals from the frames attached to the traceback object, but restoring interpreter state from that is not possible; you'd have to engineer your program to allow resuming from a saved state.

Comment: Besides, if a programming error causes a traceback, your program is in a bad state. You can't just restart the program from that bad state, it'd just crash again. And if you are dealing with a recoverable exception (not a programming error, but, say, a URL that won't load), why not just handle the exception, recover, and continue on?

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions! Sure, I would not want to resume a bad code. I am dealing with large sets of data files and sometimes those files are corrupted, which yields in an error, e.g. `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes ...`.

Comment: Then why not just catch that exception and continue on with the next file?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I am doing now, I just thought there might be a better solution to a general problem of this kind.

Comment: A little late, but you may want to try Better Exceptions. It shows variable values from the traceback to aid debugging: https://github.com/Qix-/better-exceptions